# CSS Transitions not transitioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, transition

So I have the following JS :

```
$('.metric-number, .compareToTotal').css({opacity : "0"}).on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $('.forum-select-button').css({'display' : 'inline-block',
                                   'opacity' : '1'});
});
```

And the CSS :

```
.metric-number, .compareToTotal, .forum-select-button{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

So the initial animation works, but the animation on the `.forum-select-button` does not perform the transition, but simply sets the opacity to 1.0. It is a Bootstrap button element if that helps, though I don't think its the element, because I've switched the rolls and then the '.metric-number' and '.compareToTotal' elements don't animate.

Comment: Are you trying to show the animation when passing throught the button? If you do, I think you should use a selector as `:hover`

Comment: No sorry, this happens after an onclick event for another button.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or a codepen.io?

Comment: @JamesG. Yea sure gimme a couple minutes.

Comment: @JamesG. Here you go james : http://jsfiddle.net/27sqfc38/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitions don't run when setting the `display` property. (see [list of animatable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties))

A workaround is to set the height to `0`:

```
.forum-select-button {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then set the height to `auto`:

```
  $('.forum-select-button').css({
    'height': 'auto',
    'opacity': '1'
  });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/27sqfc38/1/)**

Another approach is set animation keyframes and toggle a class when you want to show and hide the element.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/27sqfc38/2/)**

Related:

- [Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Comment: You may have to set overflow:hidden if the button has children.

Comment: [Here is a useful list of CSS animated properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

Comment: Humm, this does fix my issue. Completely messes my styling though. I'm gonna leave it open a tad longer to see if someone gets it before I re-do my styling.

Comment: Ohh man, that looks like exactly what I want! The hidden element doesn't even occupy space. Lemme see if I can integrate it :D.

Comment: Yup, that fiddle is exactly what I wanted. Had to make some minor changes but its perfect now!